# How do you cross-check a dictionary with a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say I have a list

```
list: [keith, roger, david], [5, nobody, 31], [attack, thomas, 4]
```

and a dictionary

```
dictionary: '55': <Trachea>, 'Roger': <Bert>
```

I want to delete the items in the dictionary that don't match up with the SECOND part of the list of lists. In this example, I'd want to get rid of '55':  but not 'Roger': . Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "the SECOND part of the list of lists"? Do you mean the second item in each sublist, or the second sublist? In any case, why is this hard? Iterate over the pairs in the dictionary, check the keys exist in the appropriate part of your list.

Comment: Or, if it's a large list, read the appropriate comparator items into a hashtable of their own.

Comment: Haha, so much for their being only one way to do it in python. Take your pick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# myList = [['keith', 'roger', 'david'], [5, 'nobody', 31], ['attack', 'thomas', 4]]
# myDict = {'55': '...', 'roger': '...'}

secondElements = {x[1] for x in myList}

filteredDict = {k:v for k,v in myDict.items() if (k in secondElements)}

print(filteredDict)
# prints: {'roger': '...'}
```

There are quicker ways to do it, but making a set `secondElements` will accelerate the queries and make it `O(1)` time. I edited your list because there were case-sensitivity issues, but you could also use `(k.lower() in secondElements)`.

Comment: 'secondElements = {x[1] for x in myList}' this line throws an exception in python 2.6/2.7

Comment: for some reason python is saying that  secondElements = {x[1] for x in symbVol}
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.. the problem is the for for some reason

Comment: @Fred: you can just do `set(x[1] for x in myList)` and `dict((k,v) for k,v in myDict.items() if (k in SecondElements))`. I was using python3 syntax for set and dict comprehensions for clarity, which is equivalent to `set(...)` and `dict(...)` in python2.X

Answer (score 2):

OR:

```
seconds = set(x[1] for x in d)
dict((k,v) for k,v in dd.iteritems() if k.lower() in seconds)
```

Edited to not create list each time

Comment: This will recreate the list `[x[1] for x in d]` every time, resulting in an `O(N^2)` algorithm when an `O(N)` algorithm is possible. It will also be twice as slow compared as other `O(N^2)` implementations due to use of `in` and a list. This is not to say that it is a bad solution if the size is small, it is certainly concise.

Comment: Edited to not create list each time

Comment: @Artsiom: I'd remove the downvote but it's not mine. Also note that `.iteritems()` is deprecated in favor of simple `.items()`.

Comment: @ninjagecko, I think you're wrong about it creating a new list every time. I tested it, and it only created the list once.

Comment: @senderle: How odd... I tested it with `[x for x in range(5) if x in [(lambda:print(1))(),3]]` and it is re-evaluating the query many times. Maybe the compiler is optimizing something behind our backs! **edit**: I still think I am correct: `millionRange=range(10**6) ; [x for x in range(100) if x in [y for y in millionRange]]` is much slower than `range(5)`.

Comment: @ninjagecko, that _is_ weird. But it's slightly different from what I did: `dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k.lower() in [get_item(x, 1) for x in lol])` where `get_item` prints `1` and returns `x[1]`.

Comment: @ninjagecko, Ok, I did a more complete test, and you're right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
nested = [['keith', 'roger', 'david'], [5, 'nobody', 31], ['attack', 'thomas', 4]]
seconds = [row[1] for row in nested]
d = {'55': 'Trachea', 'Roger': 'Bert'}
d = dict(((key, val) for (key, val) in d.items() if key.lower() in seconds))
```

Comment: Actually, that will fail because string comparisons are not case insensitive, let me edit it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a intermediate set and check against it:

```
# create set to check against
seconds = set(x[1] for x in list_of_lists)

# remove matching keys
for k in my_dict.keys():
  if k not in seconds:
     delete my_dict[k]
```

Easy. Runs in O(N) time, with O(N) storage.
Note that in your example, the capitalization will not match ('roger' != 'Roger')

Answer (score -1):

`>>> dict_ = {'Roger': 'Bert', 55: 'trachea'}`
`a=[['keith', 'roger', 'david'], [5, 'nobody', 31], ['attack', 'thomas', 4]]`
`>>> def delete(x):

...     del dict_[x]`

`>>> map(lambda x: delete(x),filter(lambda x:x not in a[1],dict_))`

Comment: @Beni Cherniavsky-Paskin:`map(lambda x: delete(x),filter(lambda x:x not in a[1],dict_))
[None, None]
>>> dict_
{}
`It goes 'I want to delete the items in the dictionary that don't match up with the SECOND part of the list of lists.'He also says he don't want roger alone,if that is the case he can check in the delete function.